# Best UML diagram for representing data exchange

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, data-exchange

I have a logic between two nodes that exchange some data. Something like:

1. Node1 sends message1 to Node2 through channel1
2. Node2 validates message1
3. Node2 sends message2 trough channel1
4. Node1 receives message2
5. ...

What's the right UML diagram that allows me to represent this data exchange?

I use Enterprise Architect so I can use also other diagram types with i.

Comment: You should be clear about your wording. Data can mean anything, but most common it is used with an emphasis on "larger amount of bytes". A message is an operation call. Data are part of the parameters being used in conjunction with the message exchange. Be aware of the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple sequence diagram!

In sequence diagrams you show the message exchange between objects.

Comment: Ok this seems what I need. I'll check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In UML you can use communication diagram.

We use BPMN Process diagram often. It is better readable and provides more functionality, specific events, etc.